# Extend ApiGateProxyEvent type of aws-lambda

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda

I want to extend the `ApiGateProxyEvent` of `aws-lambda` in d.ts.

I tried something like this but it replaced the whole APIGatewayProxyEvent instead of extending them.

```
declare namespace AWSLambda {
  interface APIGatewayProxyEvent {
    body: any;
    user: any;
  }
}
```

Next I tried this:

```
import 'aws-lambda';

declare module 'aws-lambda' {
  interface APIGatewayProxyEvent {
    body: any;
    user: any;
  }
}
```

but I got this error:

```
Duplicate identifier 'APIGatewayProxyEvent'.ts(2300)
api-gateway-proxy.d.ts(60, 13): 'APIGatewayProxyEvent' was also declared here.
```

My typescript version is 4.7.4 and here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the source of [aws-lambda](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aws-lambda/index.d.ts#L94), the namespace will be `AWSLambda`.

Then what you need to do in `.d.ts` file will look like this:

`custom.d.ts`

```
declare namespace AWSLambda {
  export interface APIGatewayProxyEvent {
    // body: any; // body should be a string, maybe you need another property name
    user: any;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but this did not work, the whole interface APIGatewayProxyEvent is still replaced. meaning the only field I could access is event.user and nothing else.

Comment: @lueenavarro have you resolved the issue somehow? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was using following notation until version 8.10.45 (maybe few patches more) of `@types/aws-lambda`:

```
// without import 'aws-lambda'

declare module 'aws-lambda' {
  export interface APIGatewayProxyEvent {
    user: any;
  }
}
```

Since version 8.10.61 they changed `APIGatewayProxyEvent` from interface to type, so I needed to change it to:

```
// without import 'aws-lambda'

declare module 'aws-lambda' {
  export interface APIGatewayProxyEventBase<TAuthorizerContext> {
    user: any;
  }
}
```

Works with latest version too (@types/aws-lambda@8.10.102)